# how to retrieve chat conversation text from yahoo messenger using c#?

Tags: c#

I am working on a window application using c#. i want to retrieve chat conversion text from yahoo messenger using c#. what api should  i used to do this? if you have any idea then tell me ,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a post on CodeGuru giving code to do exactly that: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/instantmessaging/comments.php/c6225/?thread=15297 (though I haven't tried it).